# jquery can't select unique elements using classes

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax on some auto generated html elements from django. I saw that you do this by selecting the instances via the class, but I can't seem to get it working. What do I have wrong here?

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fix-button').on('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var $issue_id = $(this);

          

          $.ajax({
              url: '{% url "fix_issue" %}',
              type: 'POST',
              datatype: 'json',
              data: {
                issueid: $issue_id.val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                action: 'post'
              },
              success: function (json) {
                document.getElementById("fixed_bool").innerHTML = json['result']
                console.log(json)
              },
              error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

              }
          });
        });
      });
```

html

```
<button class = "fix-button" value = "{{ issue.id }}">Fix</button>
```

views.py

```
def FixView(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        result = ''
        id = int(request.POST.get('issueid'))
        issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, id=id)
        if issue.fixed == False:
            issue.fixed = True
            result = str(issue.fixed)
            issue.save()
        else:
            issue.fixed = False
            result = str(issue.fixed)
            issue.save()

        return JsonResponse({'result': result, })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend was actually working, but the label that switches between true and false was the thing that wasn't properly updating. To fix this, I added unique id's to the label, `<span id = "{{ issue.id }}">{{ issue.fixed }}</span>` and got the unique id using

```
var issue_id = $(this).val()
document.getElementById(issue_id).innerHTML = json['result']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add an eventlistener to essentially, a list, instead of a single element.

Try using the `.each()` method after grabbing the element.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: How would I implement .each() into my case? I tried `$(document).ready(function() {$('.fix-button').each(function() {$(this).on('submit', function(event){` but it still doesn't seem to work